# warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments just in some GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings

gcc -v:
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)

```
#define d_write_log_evolved(old_fmt, args...) \
    do \
    { char new_fmt[2048] = {0}; \
      time_t timep; \
      struct tm *p; \
      timep = time(&timep); \
      p = localtime(&timep); \
      sprintf(new_fmt, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d [process %d][thread %lu]: ", \
              (int)(1900+p->tm_year), \
              (int)(1+p->tm_mon), \
              (int)(p->tm_mday), \
              (int)(p->tm_hour), \
              (int)(p->tm_min), \
              (int)(p->tm_sec), \
              getpid(), \
              pthread_self()); \
      strcat(new_fmt, old_fmt); \
      FILE *logfp = fopen(CCDAEMON_LOG, "a"); \
      fprintf(logfp, new_fmt, ##args); \
      fclose(logfp); \
    } \
    while (0)

d_write_log_evolved("[err] compile %s failed, thread will exit.\n", file);//here no warning.

d_write_log_evolved("socket() error, thread exit.\n"); //here have the warning.
```

When I pass some args to d_write_log_evolved(), then there's no warning reported, but without args, there always warning:warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

This really trouble me although program can be running properly.

BTW, there's no such warning under Scientific Linux.

Could you tell me how to eliminate this warning? Thanks!

PS. below is preprocessing result.
without agrs:

```
do { char new_fmt[2048] = {0}; time_t timep; struct tm *p; timep = time(&timep); p = localtime(&timep); sprintf(new_fmt, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d [process %d][thread %lu]: ", (int)(1900+p->tm_year), (int)(1+p->tm_mon), (int)(p->tm_mday), (int)(p->tm_hour), (int)(p->tm_min), (int)(p->tm_sec), getpid(), pthread_self()); strcat(new_fmt, "socket() error, thread exit.\n"); FILE *logfp = fopen("/tmp/ccdcc.log", "a"); fprintf(logfp, new_fmt); fclose(logfp); } while (0);
```

with args:

```
do { char new_fmt[2048] = {0}; time_t timep; struct tm *p; timep = time(&timep); p = localtime(&timep); sprintf(new_fmt, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d [process %d][thread %lu]: ", (int)(1900+p->tm_year), (int)(1+p->tm_mon), (int)(p->tm_mday), (int)(p->tm_hour), (int)(p->tm_min), (int)(p->tm_sec), getpid(), pthread_self()); strcat(new_fmt, "[ERR] send msg to client %s failed.\n"); FILE *logfp = fopen("/tmp/ccdcc.log", "a"); fprintf(logfp, new_fmt, inet_ntoa(host.sin_addr)); fclose(logfp); } while (0);
```

Comment: Start by looking at the preprocessor output to see if it's invalid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Added the preprocessing result, no issue since program can be running properly.